# Add new Item in first of database (position 0)

Tags: java, android, database

In my program , I read data from server and save into database . when i get data and save them in database . When I have new post in server , I can get new post and add to database too. But I want to add my new post at first of database . Now They add to the end of database .

I check the new post like this :

```
    public boolean rowIdExists(String StrId) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("select Id from " + TBL_NAME
            + " where Id_Main=?", new String[]{StrId});
    boolean exists = (cursor.getCount() > 0);
    return exists;


}
```

and add them like this :

```
  public boolean insertData(String id_main, String title, String category, 
   String image, String content, int fav, String link) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
    cv.put(Id_Main, id_main);
    cv.put(titleColumn, title);
    cv.put(categoryColumn, category);
    cv.put(imageColumn, image);
    cv.put(contentColumn, content);
    cv.put(favColumn, fav);
    cv.put(linkColumn, link);

    long result = db.insert(TBL_NAME, null, cv);
    if (result == -1)
        return false;
    else
        return true;
}
```

and here I get data and them :

```
   private void getPostsnEW(final Integer page, Integer limit) {

    getPosts(null, page, limit, new RemoteCallback<ResponseBody>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(ResponseBody responseBody) {

            try {
                JSONArray data = new JSONArray(responseBody.string());
                for (int i = 0; i < data.length(); i++) {
                    position_ = i;
                    check = getPosts_(data);
                    Log.i("NewData", check.get(i).getTitle());
                    if (!mydb.rowIdExists(check.get(i).getId())){
                        Log.i("NewData",check.get(i).getId()+"nistesh");
                        mydb.insertData(check.get(i).getId(), check.get(i).getTitle(), check.get(i).getCategory().getName(), check.get(i).getFeaturedImage().get(0).getUrl(), check.get(i).getContent(), 0, check.get(i).getLink());
                    }else {
                        Log.i("NewData",check.get(i).getId()+"hastesh");
                    }
                }

            } catch (Exception e) {


                Log.i("NewData__", mydb.rowIdExists(check.get(position_).getId()) + "----" + position_);
                //mydb.insertData(check.get(position_).getId(), check.get(position_).getTitle(), check.get(position_).getCategory().getName(), "", check.get(position_).getContent(), 0, check.get(position_).getLink());

            }
            int lastId = Integer.parseInt(txtsSave.get(0).getId_main());
            int newId = Integer.parseInt(check.get(0).getId());
            Log.i("NewData_ids", lastId + "\n" + newId + "");
            if (lastId < newId) {
                NewPost.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                Log.i("NewData", "New Post :-)");

            } else {
                Log.i("NewData", "No New Post :-(");
                NewPost.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }


        }

        @Override
        public void onUnauthorized() {
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailed(Throwable throwable) {
            Log.i("NewData", "onFailed" + throwable.getMessage());
        }
    });
```

I just want to add them in 0 position of database .
any suggestion ?

Answer (score 0):

in query you can make order by desc or ask by column name 
example 
SELECT * FROM Customers
ORDER BY Country DESC;